# How to use Stanford parser

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I downloaded the Stanford parser 2.0.5 and use Demo2.java source code that is in the package, but After I compile and run the program it has many errors. 
A part of my program is:

```
public class testStanfordParser {
/** Usage: ParserDemo2 [[grammar] textFile] */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String grammar = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz";
    String[] options = { "-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories" };
    LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(grammar, options);
    TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
    GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
 ...
```

the errors are:

```
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:408)
at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readStreamFromString(IOUtils.java:356)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromSerializedFile(LexicalizedParser.java:594)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromFile(LexicalizedParser.java:389)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:157)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:143)
at testStanfordParser.main(testStanfordParser.java:19).                                             Loading parser from text file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/BufferedReader;
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromTextFile(LexicalizedParser.java:528)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromFile(LexicalizedParser.java:391)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:157)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:143)
at testStanfordParser.main(testStanfordParser.java:19)
```

please help me to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: I solved this problem. The problem was the conflict between stanford parser package and stanford coreNLP package in my workspace.

Comment: Have a look at this question [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084556/stanford-lexicalized-parser-load-model-error

Comment: @SahelSoft can you explain what exactly you did to solve this?

Comment: I incorrectly added both of Stanford parser package and Stanford CoreNLP package to my project. after removing the Stanford parser, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Stanford parser to extract entities like name ,location,organization.

Here is my code:

```
public class stanfrdIntro {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException,
  {

        String serializedClassifier = "classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";


        AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier
                .getClassifierNoExceptions(serializedClassifier);

       String s1 = "Good afternoon Rahul Kulhari, how are you today?";

       s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
       String  t=classifier.classifyWithInlineXML(s1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(t).toArray()));

    }
       private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<PERSON>(.+?)</PERSON>");

private static Set<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
    final Set<String> tagValues = new HashSet<String>();
    //final Set<String> tagValues = new TreeSet();
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    return tagValues;
}
```

This might help you but i am extracting only entities.

Answer (score 4):

All grammars are located in the included models jar.
Is the "stanford-parser-2.0.5-models.jar" in the execution directory or classpath?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The model is located in the execution directory. I change the code with <<    String grammar = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "C:/project/models/englishPCFG.ser.gz";   >>   but It has errors.

Comment: check your stanford-parser.jar. It seems that you are using a older one. At least the edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromString is not there.

Comment: At least in version 1.5 was not such a method in IOUtils