# Stanford Lexicalized Parser Load Model error

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using the NLP Parser on C# under visual studio 2012.
NuGet installed fine, can compile the simple example.
I have noticed an issue with the model loader:

```
        try
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(System.IO.File.Exists(full) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
            LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(full);
            lp.setOptionFlags(new String[] { "-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories" });
            //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            //DemoDP(lp, fileName);
            //else
            DemoAPI(lp);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
```

I get some sort of file reading formatting error:

C:\NLPTest\bin\x86\Debug\englishPCFG.ser.gz: expecting BEGIN block; got ??

The model file is about 8 MB, but I don't have a clue about the format of this model file.
Is there somewhere an official file I can download that is sure to be working?

Answer (score 6):

Right I have found the issue, as suspected it was due to the old format of the model.
The way I did it solve it was :

- download the project files version 2013
- open the jar filed called stanford-parser-3.2.0-models
- extract the englishPCFG.ser.gz
- pronounce abracadabra and no more format error

Hope it helps other people!